# Kernel version change causes error

Tags: linux-kernel

I modify the kernel version in the Makefile

```
   VERSION = 3
   PATCHLEVEL = 12
   SUBLEVEL = 0
   EXTRAVERSION = -33-generic
```

While I expect to have 3.12.0-33-generic.

However, after successfully building the kernel, I found the error during the boot process,

```
Could not open moddep file /lib/modules/3.x.x.x-22-dirty/modules.dep.bin
```

I was wondering why it appends the 'dirty' to the expected kernel version.

After using the "grep" command, I found there are two files indicated that my own built kernel version appended the "dirty" right after the kernel version.

```
/kernel-source/include/config/kernel.release
/kernel-source/generated/utsrelease.h
In the first file: 3.12.0-33-generic-dirty
In the second file: #define UTS_RELEASE "3.12.0-33-generic-dirty"
```

Is there anyway to fix this ? thanks.

====updated post====

my steps to have the expected kernel version without having "-dirty" or "+"

1. Modifying the Makefile as the following

   ```
   VERSION = 3

   PATCHLEVEL = 12

   SUBLEVEL = 0

   EXTRAVERSION =
   ```
2. Using git command to commit all changes
3. `Make menuconfig`
4. `Make -j8 LOCALVERSION="-33-generic"`
5. The output kernel version is `3.12.0-33-generic`

That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'-dirty' will be appended to kernel version if there are uncommitted changes in your Linux kernel repository.

To get rid of it, commit all of the uncommitted changes.

Alternatively, build kernel with LOCALVERSION:

```
make LOCALVERSION="-33-generic"
```